# Kubernetes Deployment successfully, but not displaying the updated content

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-eks

I am a newbee in Kubernetes.

I have a Jenkins pipeline to deploy microservices [Spring Boot] into Kubernetes cluster [ EKS ]. It is in working condition and able to deploy into EKS cluster successfully.

> For first time [ when Deployment / Service / Pod is not present in EKS
>   ] application is deploying and displaying the content properly, but
>   after that Application is deploying into cluster but not showing the
>   updated content, it is showing the old content.

If i remove the existing Deployment , Service and Pod, then it is deploying and displaying the new content.

Any clue if i am missing something.

Comment: Can you tell more details like deployment configuration, which Docker image repository is being used, are you using helm or any blue ocean template in Jenkins. Please put those details too. I can say run the jar first before deploying and check your jar is reflecting your code or not after build stage?

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick .. you have to use a pattern in pom and deployment yaml file that pattern need to be replaced using sed command in jenkins file

in pom

```
<image>registry.hub.docker.com/xxxx/yyyy:#BUILD_NUMBER</image>
```

In deloyment.yaml file

```
image: registry.hub.docker.com/xxxx/yyyy:#BUILD_NUMBER
```

and in jenkins file

```
sh "sed -i 's/#BUILD_NUMBER/${BUILD_NUMBER}/g' pom.xml"
sh "sed -i 's/#BUILD_NUMBER/${BUILD_NUMBER}/g' kubedeploy.yaml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the image tag is the same? If yes then provide different for each build.

If you need the same image tag then change imagePullPolicy to Always.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/

If the problem still persists check deployment rollout.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Share your YAML file, if still not able to fix it.

Comment: I do have imagePullPolicy to Always set .. but it is not working                                                                  ---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: springbootapp
  name: springbootapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springbootapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springbootapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: xxxx/yyyy/zzzz:1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: springbootapp

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using "latest" tag image in your POD specification. If yes, you can do either of 2 things -

1. Instead of latest tag use specific tag.
2. If you still want to use "latest" tag of image then patch deployment using below command on Linux. If you are on Windows just use bash shell or git shell -

`kubectl patch deployment <deploymentName> -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"date\":\"`date +'%s'`\"}}}}}"`

Let me know if that resolves your issue.

`

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <to>
         <repository>docker.io/repo</repository>
         <tag>${project.version}</tag>
      </to>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

`
Let me know if this plugin tag helps.

Comment: Thanks ..your first option works .. but still not satisfied, because didn't find any way to use specific tag name properly in maven pom and deployment yaml [ please note it is googles jib plugin, i am using to create docker image ]

Comment: `
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <to>
             <repository>docker.io/repo</repository>
             <tag>${project.version}</tag>
          </to>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>`

Comment: Thanks .. I have done it .. There is a trick .. you have to use a pattern in pom and deployment yaml file that pattern need to be replaced using sed command in jenkins file .. it works for me ..                                                                                    
        sh "sed -i 's/#BUILD_NUMBER/${BUILD_NUMBER}/g' pom.xml"
        sh "sed -i 's/#BUILD_NUMBER/${BUILD_NUMBER}/g' kubedeploy.yaml"